# Continuous testing for android with gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I want to let gradle runs forever and run tests if something changed, so I can know if the thing that I changed break something without having to run tests locally.

Gradle have an incubating continuous feature, so Im trying with:

```
./gradlew test --continuous
```

but it always prints:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.311 secs

222 tasks in build, out of which 95 (43%) were executed
110  (50%) up-to-date
 17   (8%) no-source
 95  (43%) not cacheable

Waiting for changes to input files of tasks... (ctrl-d to exit)
modified: .../app/build/generated/source/r/debug/android/support/compat/R.java
modified: .../app/build/generated/source/r/debug/android/support/coreui/R.java
modified: .../app/build/generated/source/r/debug/android/support/coreutils/R.java
and some more changes
Change detected, executing build...
```

and it never run the tests, its always building the project.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would have a Continous Integration tool like Jenkins and configure Jenkins to rebuild the project and run the tests at each commit to a specific branch. I think it's better to work this way.

Comment: @jeprubio but this is handly for some cases